# How to make random numbers with variables in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I encountered a problem while programming in Python, and here's a bite of my program:

```
import random 

p = raw_input('Percent Probability Program\nWhat percent?\n ')

r1 = random.randint(p, 100)
```

It gave me an error that the first value in the random command wasn't an integer. Please help!

Comment: specifying the input as an int with `p = int(raw_input())` is likely what you need

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2

`raw_input` returns a `str` object, which is basically a string - no math operations can be performed on strings, and it's not the correct type for `randint`.

You can either convert your input to `int` using `int(raw_input())` or just use the method `input()`, which returns an evaluated value (in your case, it should return an int)

## Python 3

In python 3, the `input` function returns an `str` object, so converting it to int will be `int(input())`

Comment: This holds for python 2. In python 3 `input()` does not perform any evaluation and always returns a string.

Comment: Suggesting `input()` in Python 2 is generally not a good idea, because it performs more general evaluation, not just converting to `int`.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis He used `raw_input`, which means that he's using Python 2.